# Getting connection error while web scrapping in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-scraping, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I am using EFS to store python packages for Lambda and I have been running this simple code to check connection of the site

```
import json 
import sys
sys.path.append("/mnt/access")
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def lambda_handler(event, context):

     url = "http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/credit"

     print(url)

     page = requests.get(url)
   # soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
     print(page)
```

This is the CloudWatch logs

> [ERROR] ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.wordhippo.com',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
> /what-is/another-word-for/credit.html (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x7eff5fa618e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110]
> Connection timed out')) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 126, in lambda_handler
>     page = requests.get(url)   File "/mnt/access/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
>     return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "/mnt/access/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
>     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "/mnt/access/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
>     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/mnt/access/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
>     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/mnt/access/requests/adapters.py", line 565, in send
>     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

Comment: Please do not post errors as screenshots, but use properly formatted code blcoks. Also your code is not a valid lambda function.

Comment: Sorry for all the issues. Edited as per requirement

Comment: Is the lambda in a VPC?

Comment: Yes its in a default aws VPC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda function in a VPC [does not have](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/) internet access if its in public subnets. Default VPC has only public subnets.

The easiest way to enable internet access to your function is simply **not placing** it in a VPC.